# Where do I ask about research topics and departments?

Tags: discussion, tagging, allowed-questions, asking-questions, cross-posting

I would like to ask the community where I could apply for a PhD, given some (advanced) topics that I really like. 
If I ask it on math.se or mathoverflow, I'm afraid that they send me to academia.se, as the question is not a math problem.
If I ask it on academia.se, anyway, there are almost no mathematicians, and it's very unlikely to find people in my own subfield.

What can I do about it? 
Can we make a special tag?
Is there already a place where to ask such questions?

Thanks.

Comment: Mathematicians (and computer scientists) are actually overrepresented at Academia.SE. Looking at the first two pages of top Academia users, I recognize a number of names from MO/MSE. So it's not unreasonable to ask there. That said, your question looks like a shopping recommendation (you are shopping for a PhD program) and those rarely work at SE, on any site.

Comment: The place to ask about it is the institution where you did your undergraduate degree, where they know you, and where they are probably set up to answer questions like yours.

Comment: I found my supervisor by going through the web pages of good universities I would like to attend. *Hmm, he's a professor...does group theory...research looks interesting...*. I then sent an e-mail to anyone who looked promising (1 per department, mind!). I do agree with Gerry Myerson: ask people in your department. However, often you will end up with a bias towards what the people you ask find interesting (the same goes for asking at this -or any!- website). So doing the leg work yourself has some merit.